# Where did my Chrome bookmarklets go?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, bookmarklet

I'm using 8.0.552.224 Chrome.  Sometime, over the holidays, my bookmarklets nearly completely disappeared.  The bookmarklets are present in the default screen that shows when I open a new tab.  However, when I navigate away from that tab (browse further), the bookmarklets bar (usually appearing below the address field) is gone.

Can anybody tell me why the bookmarklets are no longer persisteent and how to get them back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
On the 'newly opened tab' window, hover your mouse over the bookmarklets, then right click & choose:

```
Always show bookmarks bar
```

That is all.